# How do you use `FileReader` or a web worker or similar that needs an external file in Stack Snippets?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets, faq-proposed

I need to show an example of my problem using `FileReader`. How can I do that with Stack Snippets? They don't let you have multiple files. The same thing happens when I need to ask about something with a web worker or other things that require an external file...

Answer (score 7):

It's awkward, no question. You can do it with a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and (in the case of a web worker) [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

### `FileReader`

**If** the specific content you're reading doesn't matter, you can use a `file` input:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    // Read the file
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function() {
        console.log(`Read ${fileReader.result.byteLength} bytes`);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]); 
});
```

```html
Pick any file: <input type="file">
```

If the specific content matters, create a `Blob` with the content and use `createObjectURL` to get a URL for it. Here's a text example:

```js
// Create a blob containing the text
const blob = new Blob([
    document.getElementById("data").textContent
], { type: "text/plain" })

// Read the "file"
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
    console.log("Contents:");
    for (const line of fileReader.result.split(/\r?\n/)) {
        console.log(line);
    }
};
fileReader.readAsText(blob);
```

```html
<!-- Here's the "file" we'll read. Since the type is text/plain, it won't be run by the browser -->
<script id="data" type="text/plain">
Testing 1 2 3.
Testing.
This is a test.
</script>
```

That's reading text, but you can create a `Blob` with any content you need. Here's one reading a PNG "file":

```js
const PNG_HEADER_1 = 0x89504E47; // Big-endian first Uint32 of PNG header
const PNG_HEADER_2 = 0x0D0A1A0A; // Big-endian second Uint32 of PNG header
const TYPE_IHDR = 0x49484452;    // Big-endian type of IHDR chunk

// Create a blob containing the data
const blob = createData();

// Read the "file"
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function() {
    const dv = new DataView(fileReader.result);
    if (dv.byteLength >= 24 &&
        dv.getUint32(0) === PNG_HEADER_1 &&
        dv.getUint32(4) === PNG_HEADER_2 &&
        dv.getUint32(12) === TYPE_IHDR) {
        const width = dv.getUint32(16);
        const height = dv.getUint32(20);
        console.log(`The PNG is ${width} by ${height} pixels`);
    } else {
        console.log(`The data is not in PNG format.`);
    }
};
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

function createData() {
    return new Blob([Uint8Array.of(
        // PNG image data
        0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x52,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x64, 0x08, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3, 0x86, 0x7f,
        0x0b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x70, 0x48, 0x59, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0b,
        0x13, 0x01, 0x00, 0x9a, 0x9c, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x81, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x54, 0x78, 0xda,
        0xed, 0x9d, 0x7b, 0x6c, 0x54, 0x45, 0x1b, 0x87, 0x9f, 0x69, 0x91, 0xa5, 0xa0, 0x20, 0xb6, 0x05,
        0xc1, 0x52, 0x2e, 0x2d, 0x56, 0x84, 0x22, 0x42, 0xa0, 0x85, 0x78, 0xf9, 0x20, 0x2a, 0x97, 0xc4,
        0x86, 0x68, 0xa9, 0x40, 0x21, 0x26, 0x08, 0x08, 0xd8, 0xa0, 0x04, 0x30, 0x20, 0x18, 0xc4, 0x80,
        0x17, 0x2e, 0x6d, 0x88, 0x82, 0x22, 0xa0, 0x7f, 0xa0, 0x20, 0xa5, 0x82, 0x34, 0x8a, 0xa5, 0x26,
        0x96, 0x9b, 0x6d, 0x11, 0xa8, 0x41, 0xe4, 0x96, 0x2a, 0xc8, 0xad, 0xa6, 0x4a, 0x13, 0xac, 0x40,
        0x69, 0x69, 0xfb, 0x7e, 0x7f, 0x8c, 0xcb, 0x76, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0x2d, 0x5d, 0xad, 0xa9, 0xdd, 0xf7,
        0x49, 0x36, 0x73, 0xce, 0x9c, 0x39, 0xb3, 0x73, 0x76, 0xe7, 0x77, 0x66, 0xde, 0x33, 0x67, 0xde,
        0x31, 0x4f, 0x3e, 0x29, 0x82, 0xa2, 0x28, 0x5e, 0x09, 0xd2, 0x9f, 0x40, 0x51, 0x7c, 0xd3, 0xc2,
        0xb9, 0x91, 0x99, 0xa9, 0x3f, 0x86, 0xa2, 0x38, 0x49, 0x48, 0xd0, 0x16, 0x44, 0x51, 0xb4, 0x8b,
        0xa5, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x45, 0x51, 0x81, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x51, 0x54, 0x20, 0x8a, 0xa2,
        0x02, 0x51, 0x14, 0x15, 0x88, 0xa2, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x14, 0x45, 0x05, 0xa2, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44,
        0x51, 0x54, 0x20, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0x02, 0x51, 0x14, 0x15, 0x88, 0xa2, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x14, 0x45, 0x05,
        0xa2, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x45, 0x51, 0x81, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x51, 0x14, 0x15, 0x48, 0xf3,
        0x23, 0x21, 0xc1, 0x35, 0x9f, 0x5a, 0xf9, 0xfb, 0xb4, 0xd0, 0x9f, 0xc0, 0xc5, 0xa9, 0x53, 0x42,
        0x7a, 0x3a, 0x9c, 0x3e, 0x0d, 0x97, 0x2f, 0xc3, 0x5d, 0x77, 0x41, 0x9f, 0x3e, 0x30, 0x7c, 0x38,
        0xdc, 0x7f, 0xbf, 0xd1, 0x1f, 0x48, 0x05, 0x12, 0xb8, 0xe4, 0xe6, 0x0a, 0x6f, 0xbd, 0x05, 0xe0,
        0x12, 0xc2, 0xef, 0xbf, 0x43, 0x4e, 0x8e, 0xfd, 0xa8, 0xd7, 0x17, 0x15, 0x48, 0x40, 0xf3, 0xc9,
        0x27, 0x56, 0x1c, 0x0f, 0x3e, 0x28, 0x3c, 0xfb, 0x2c, 0xdc, 0x73, 0x0f, 0x94, 0x95, 0xc1, 0xd1,
        0xa3, 0xb0, 0x73, 0xa7, 0xbb, 0x70, 0x14, 0x15, 0x48, 0xc0, 0xf1, 0xeb, 0xaf, 0x36, 0x7c, 0xe9,
        0x25, 0x68, 0xdf, 0xde, 0x8a, 0xc1, 0xe1, 0x80, 0x87, 0x1f, 0xb6, 0x9f, 0xda, 0x7c, 0xff, 0xbd,
        0x90, 0x99, 0x09, 0xc7, 0x8f, 0x43, 0x65, 0x25, 0xf4, 0xe8, 0x01, 0xc9, 0xc9, 0xd0, 0xaf, 0x9f,
        0xf1, 0xb0, 0x09, 0x00, 0xb6, 0x6c, 0x11, 0xd6, 0xae, 0x85, 0xbc, 0x3c, 0x9b, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x22,
        0x24, 0x24, 0x18, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x85, 0x75, 0xeb, 0xe0, 0xe0, 0x41, 0x08, 0x0a, 0x82, 0x11, 0x23,
        0x60, 0xe2, 0x44, 0x30, 0xc6, 0x78, 0xe4, 0x91, 0x9e, 0x2e, 0xac, 0x5f, 0x0f, 0xb9, 0xb9, 0x70,
        0xe3, 0x06, 0xf4, 0xeb, 0x07, 0x93, 0x27, 0x43, 0xc7, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x8b, 0x37, 0x27, 0x47, 0xc8,
        0xce, 0xb6, 0xdd, 0xc7, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x08, 0x0b, 0x83, 0x21, 0x43, 0x20, 0x29, 0x09, 0xda, 0xb4,
        0x51, 0xf1, 0xab, 0x40, 0xea, 0xe1, 0xee, 0xbb, 0xe1, 0xc2, 0x05, 0xd8, 0xb5, 0x0b, 0x46, 0x8e,
        0x14, 0xda, 0xb5, 0xab, 0xbb, 0xd2, 0x2c, 0x5a, 0x64, 0x6a, 0xd9, 0x2f, 0xf0, 0xda, 0x6b, 0xc2,
        0xf2, 0xe5, 0x42, 0xcf, 0x9e, 0x9e, 0xe7, 0xa6, 0xa5, 0x41, 0x7e, 0xbe, 0x8d, 0x2f, 0x2b, 0x83,
        0xf5, 0xeb, 0xa1, 0x63, 0x47, 0x6b, 0xf3, 0x14, 0x16, 0xba, 0xd2, 0x67, 0x64, 0x40, 0x44, 0x84,
        0x30, 0x6c, 0x98, 0xe7, 0x77, 0xa6, 0xa6, 0xba, 0xf2, 0x00, 0x38, 0x70, 0x00, 0x7e, 0xfa, 0x49,
        0x58, 0xb5, 0x4a, 0x68, 0xdb, 0xd6, 0x7b, 0x79, 0x45, 0x84, 0x95, 0x2b, 0x61, 0xef, 0x5e, 0xf7,
        0xe3, 0xc5, 0xc5, 0xb0, 0x7d, 0x3b, 0x1c, 0x3a, 0x24, 0x2c, 0x5b, 0x26, 0x2a, 0x12, 0x1f, 0xe8,
        0x53, 0xac, 0xbf, 0x18, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0x86, 0x9b, 0x36, 0x19, 0x26, 0x4e, 0x34, 0x4c, 0x99, 0x62,
        0x2b, 0x4e, 0x4e, 0x8e, 0x50, 0x59, 0xe9, 0xe9, 0xbe, 0x78, 0xc8, 0x10, 0x21, 0x35, 0x55, 0xc8,
        0xc8, 0x10, 0xd6, 0xae, 0x15, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0x85, 0xea, 0x6a, 0xc3, 0xf6, 0xed, 0xde, 0xf3, 0x2f,
        0x2e, 0x86, 0x55, 0xab, 0x84, 0xcd, 0x9b, 0x85, 0x91, 0x23, 0xe5, 0x66, 0x85, 0xaf, 0xac, 0xf4,
        0x8c, 0xcf, 0xca, 0xf2, 0x9e, 0xc7, 0xcf, 0x3f, 0xc3, 0xd2, 0xa5, 0xc2, 0x96, 0x2d, 0xc2, 0x92,
        0x25, 0x42, 0x58, 0x98, 0x50, 0x52, 0x62, 0xf8, 0xec, 0x33, 0xdf, 0xd7, 0x95, 0x9d, 0x6d, 0xc5,
        0x11, 0x1a, 0x2a, 0xbc, 0xfc, 0xb2, 0xb0, 0x71, 0xa3, 0xb0, 0x75, 0xab, 0xf0, 0xf6, 0xdb, 0x42,
        0x74, 0xb4, 0x70, 0xfe, 0xbc, 0x61, 0xeb, 0x56, 0xfd, 0xff, 0x55, 0x20, 0xf5, 0xf0, 0xc8, 0x23,
        0x86, 0x25, 0x4b, 0x84, 0x81, 0x03, 0x05, 0x87, 0x43, 0x28, 0x2e, 0x36, 0xec, 0xdf, 0x6f, 0x48,
        0x4b, 0x33, 0xcc, 0x9e, 0x0d, 0x7f, 0xfc, 0xe1, 0x2e, 0x92, 0x79, 0xf3, 0x0c, 0xd1, 0xd1, 0x86,
        0x96, 0x2d, 0x0d, 0x9d, 0x3a, 0x19, 0x66, 0xcc, 0xb0, 0xf1, 0x27, 0x4e, 0x78, 0xcf, 0x7f, 0xfa,
        0x74, 0xe8, 0xde, 0xdd, 0xd0, 0xa6, 0x8d, 0xe1, 0x99, 0x67, 0xf8, 0xab, 0x25, 0x31, 0x5e, 0xe3,
        0x8b, 0x8a, 0xbc, 0xe7, 0x31, 0x75, 0x2a, 0xc4, 0xc6, 0x1a, 0x42, 0x42, 0x0c, 0x7d, 0xfb, 0x1a,
        0xa6, 0x4c, 0xb1, 0xf1, 0x07, 0x0f, 0xd6, 0x2d, 0x10, 0x80, 0x39, 0x73, 0xe0, 0xa1, 0x87, 0x0c,
        0xed, 0xda, 0x19, 0x1c, 0x0e, 0x43, 0xaf, 0x5e, 0x86, 0xb9, 0x73, 0xed, 0xb1, 0xbc, 0x3c, 0xfd,
        0xff, 0xb5, 0x8b, 0x75, 0x0b, 0xf4, 0xed, 0x6b, 0xe8, 0xdb, 0x17, 0xaa, 0xaa, 0x84, 0x8b, 0x17,
        0x85, 0xa3, 0x47, 0x61, 0xdb, 0x36, 0x38, 0x73, 0xc6, 0xf0, 0xf1, 0xc7, 0xc2, 0x0b, 0x2f, 0xd8,
        0x74, 0x55, 0x55, 0xc2, 0x8e, 0x1d, 0xb0, 0x67, 0x0f, 0x5c, 0xbc, 0x08, 0x15, 0x15, 0xe6, 0xa6,
        0x11, 0x7f, 0xf9, 0xb2, 0xf7, 0xbc, 0x7b, 0xf4, 0x70, 0x6d, 0xb7, 0x6f, 0x5f, 0x77, 0x7c, 0x69,
        0xa9, 0xf7, 0x3c, 0x7a, 0xf7, 0x76, 0xdf, 0xef, 0xd3, 0xc7, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xf9, 0xe2, 0xec, 0x59,
        0x1b, 0xce, 0x9f, 0xef, 0xad, 0x0b, 0x65, 0xea, 0x3d, 0x5f, 0x05, 0xa2, 0x78, 0x10, 0x1c, 0x6c,
        0x88, 0x8c, 0x84, 0xc8, 0x48, 0x88, 0x8d, 0x15, 0x52, 0x52, 0xe0, 0xd0, 0x21, 0xd7, 0xf1, 0x8f,
        0x3e, 0x82, 0xcc, 0x4c, 0xef, 0x7d, 0xf6, 0xaa, 0x2a, 0xef, 0xf1, 0x2d, 0x5b, 0xba, 0xe2, 0x6b,
        0x1a, 0xe0, 0xde, 0xe3, 0xff, 0x39, 0x7b, 0xe0, 0x56, 0x16, 0xb7, 0xa8, 0xae, 0x56, 0xfb, 0x43,
        0x05, 0xe2, 0x27, 0x6d, 0xda, 0xe0, 0xd1, 0x32, 0x7c, 0xf3, 0x8d, 0x0d, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0x51, 0x18,
        0x38, 0xd0, 0xa6, 0xb9, 0x7a, 0x15, 0x26, 0x4c, 0x68, 0xdc, 0x8a, 0x76, 0xec, 0x18, 0xc4, 0xc5,
        0xb9, 0xf6, 0x7f, 0xfc, 0xd1, 0x86, 0x1d, 0x3b, 0xfa, 0x3e, 0x27, 0x32, 0xd2, 0xda, 0x2e, 0x2b,
        0x56, 0x08, 0xf7, 0xde, 0xab, 0x42, 0x50, 0x1b, 0xc4, 0x4f, 0x66, 0xcf, 0x16, 0x76, 0xee, 0x14,
        0xce, 0x9f, 0x17, 0x2a, 0x2a, 0x84, 0xb2, 0x32, 0xe1, 0xc4, 0x09, 0x61, 0xf9, 0x72, 0x7b, 0xbc,
        0x53, 0x27, 0xcf, 0xbb, 0x72, 0xeb, 0xd6, 0xd0, 0xaa, 0x15, 0xfc, 0xf6, 0x1b, 0xac, 0x5e, 0xdd,
        0xf8, 0x65, 0xfc, 0xe0, 0x03, 0x38, 0x7a, 0xd4, 0x96, 0xed, 0x87, 0x1f, 0xec, 0xe3, 0x61, 0x80,
        0x81, 0x03, 0x7d, 0x9f, 0x33, 0x6a, 0x94, 0x0d, 0x97, 0x2c, 0x81, 0x5d, 0xbb, 0x84, 0xe2, 0x62,
        0xa1, 0xbc, 0xdc, 0x5e, 0xe3, 0x85, 0x0b, 0x42, 0x56, 0x96, 0x30, 0x77, 0xae, 0xae, 0xa1, 0xa4,
        0x2d, 0x48, 0x3d, 0x14, 0x16, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x7d, 0x76, 0x54, 0x48, 0x4e, 0x76, 0xed, 0x0d,
        0x18, 0x00, 0x7b, 0xf7, 0xc2, 0x9b, 0x6f, 0xba, 0xee, 0xc8, 0x71, 0x71, 0x8d, 0x5f, 0xc9, 0xa2,
        0xa2, 0x60, 0xc1, 0x02, 0xf7, 0x56, 0x20, 0x34, 0x54, 0x78, 0xfa, 0x69, 0xdf, 0xe7, 0x3c, 0xfe,
        0xb8, 0xe1, 0xf4, 0x69, 0xe1, 0xcb, 0x2f, 0xcd, 0xbf, 0x22, 0x62, 0x15, 0x48, 0x33, 0x65, 0xe5,
        0x4a, 0x21, 0x27, 0xc7, 0x8e, 0x9c, 0x17, 0x15, 0x41, 0x55, 0x15, 0xdc, 0x79, 0x27, 0xc4, 0xc4,
        0xd8, 0x81, 0xba, 0xde, 0xbd, 0x5d, 0x15, 0x73, 0xea, 0x54, 0x30, 0x46, 0x38, 0x7c, 0x18, 0xaa,
        0xab, 0x61, 0xf0, 0x60, 0x1b, 0xe7, 0x7c, 0x0a, 0xd5, 0x58, 0xcc, 0x9a, 0x05, 0xeb, 0xd6, 0x09,
        0x79, 0x79, 0xf6, 0xf1, 0xf0, 0x03, 0x0f, 0xd8, 0x81, 0x42, 0x5f, 0x63, 0x20, 0x4e, 0x9e, 0x7f,
        0xde, 0x10, 0x17, 0x27, 0x64, 0x65, 0xc1, 0xc9, 0x93, 0xb6, 0xbb, 0x18, 0x1c, 0x6c, 0xc7, 0x7e,
        0xfa, 0xf7, 0x87, 0xa1, 0x43, 0xff, 0x59, 0xbb, 0xa7, 0x39, 0x61, 0x9c, 0x6b, 0x14, 0xea, 0xbb,
        0x46, 0x4d, 0x17, 0xe7, 0x48, 0xba, 0xfe, 0x47, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x6f, 0xae, 0x36, 0x88, 0xa2, 0xa8,
        0x91, 0xae, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x45, 0x51, 0x23, 0x3d, 0x10, 0x51, 0xdb, 0x43, 0x5b, 0x10, 0x45,
        0x51, 0x81, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x51, 0x54, 0x20, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0x46, 0x7a, 0xb3, 0xe4, 0xd4,
        0x29, 0xe1, 0xeb, 0xaf, 0xe1, 0xc8, 0x11, 0xb8, 0x74, 0xc9, 0x8e, 0x96, 0x47, 0x47, 0xc3, 0x98,
        0x31, 0x78, 0x7d, 0x99, 0xaf, 0xa2, 0x42, 0xc8, 0xc8, 0xb0, 0x2f, 0x28, 0x96, 0x94, 0x40, 0x68,
        0x28, 0x0c, 0x1b, 0x66, 0xd3, 0xdf, 0x76, 0x9b, 0xf1, 0x3b, 0x6d, 0x43, 0x38, 0x7f, 0x5e, 0xc8,
        0xcf, 0x87, 0xfc, 0x7c, 0xfe, 0x7a, 0x1d, 0xc6, 0xf8, 0x34, 0xdc, 0x9b, 0x42, 0x79, 0x9b, 0x13,
        0x01, 0x37, 0x92, 0xee, 0xdb, 0x67, 0x94, 0x30, 0x6f, 0x1e, 0x0c, 0x19, 0xe2, 0x5e, 0x31, 0xde,
        0x78, 0x43, 0xdc, 0xa6, 0xb9, 0x3a, 0x19, 0x3c, 0x58, 0x3c, 0xe6, 0x58, 0x34, 0x24, 0xed, 0xdf,
        0x2d, 0xb3, 0xaf, 0xff, 0xab, 0x29, 0x94, 0xb7, 0x39, 0xd5, 0x93, 0x80, 0xeb, 0x62, 0xc5, 0xc4,
        0x08, 0x33, 0x67, 0x0a, 0x1b, 0x36, 0xd8, 0xe9, 0xb2, 0x69, 0x69, 0x42, 0x4c, 0x8c, 0x00, 0x86,
        0x8d, 0x1b, 0xdd, 0xd3, 0x1e, 0x3e, 0x6c, 0x2b, 0x50, 0x48, 0x88, 0xb0, 0x68, 0x91, 0x9d, 0xaa,
        0xba, 0x68, 0x91, 0x10, 0x12, 0x22, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0x19, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0xc4, 0xaf, 0xb4, 0x0d, 0x25,
        0x22, 0x42, 0x18, 0x3b, 0x56, 0x78, 0xe7, 0x9d, 0xba, 0xf3, 0x68, 0x2a, 0xe5, 0x55, 0x1b, 0xe4,
        0x3f, 0xcc, 0xf2, 0xe5, 0x86, 0xc7, 0x1e, 0x33, 0x84, 0x87, 0xdb, 0xe9, 0xb2, 0x51, 0x51, 0x76,
        0x4a, 0x2d, 0xd8, 0xd7, 0xd6, 0x6b, 0xb2, 0x7b, 0xb7, 0x0d, 0x13, 0x13, 0x61, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x3b,
        0x55, 0x75, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x43, 0x62, 0xa2, 0xfb, 0xf1, 0x86, 0xa6, 0x5d, 0xb6, 0x4c, 0x48, 0x48,
        0x80, 0x94, 0x14, 0x41, 0x6a, 0xcc, 0x68, 0x12, 0x11, 0x52, 0x52, 0xec, 0xb1, 0x15, 0x2b, 0x5c,
        0xf1, 0x6b, 0xd6, 0x18, 0xc6, 0x8f, 0x37, 0x74, 0xed, 0x5a, 0xf7, 0x5d, 0xbd, 0xb1, 0xca, 0xab,
        0x02, 0x09, 0x70, 0x5a, 0xb5, 0xb2, 0x61, 0xcd, 0x39, 0x1f, 0xc0, 0xcd, 0xd7, 0xdf, 0x6b, 0xcf,
        0xb7, 0x70, 0xee, 0xd7, 0x7c, 0x3d, 0xbe, 0x21, 0x69, 0xa7, 0x4d, 0x83, 0xf6, 0xed, 0x85, 0x73,
        0xe7, 0x0c, 0xfb, 0xf6, 0xb9, 0xe2, 0xf7, 0xed, 0x83, 0x73, 0xe7, 0x0c, 0xe1, 0xe1, 0xc2, 0xf4,
        0xe9, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0x8e, 0xc6, 0x2a, 0xaf, 0x0a, 0x24, 0xc0, 0xf9, 0xfc, 0x73, 0x1b, 0xd6, 0xf6,
        0x7f, 0x55, 0x52, 0x62, 0xc3, 0xda, 0x33, 0xf6, 0x9c, 0xfb, 0xce, 0xe3, 0x0d, 0x4d, 0xdb, 0xb6,
        0xad, 0x61, 0xe6, 0x4c, 0xbb, 0xbd, 0x79, 0x33, 0x54, 0x57, 0x0b, 0x55, 0x55, 0xc2, 0xa6, 0x4d,
        0xd6, 0x16, 0x9a, 0x35, 0xcb, 0x3f, 0x5f, 0x55, 0x8d, 0x55, 0x5e, 0x7d, 0x8a, 0x15, 0xc0, 0xec,
        0xde, 0x2d, 0x6c, 0xdb, 0x06, 0x9d, 0x3a, 0x09, 0xa3, 0x47, 0xbb, 0x1f, 0x2b, 0x2f, 0xb7, 0xa1,
        0xc3, 0xe1, 0x1e, 0xef, 0xdc, 0x77, 0x1e, 0x6f, 0x68, 0x5a, 0xb0, 0xdd, 0x9a, 0x11, 0x23, 0x84,
        0xac, 0x2c, 0xc3, 0xee, 0xdd, 0x82, 0x08, 0x14, 0x15, 0x19, 0x12, 0x13, 0x85, 0x3e, 0x7d, 0xfc,
        0x33, 0x90, 0x1b, 0xb3, 0xbc, 0xda, 0x82, 0x04, 0xa8, 0x38, 0xd2, 0xd2, 0x6c, 0xa5, 0x98, 0x3f,
        0x1f, 0x1c, 0x0e, 0x73, 0x4b, 0x95, 0xc5, 0x5b, 0xe5, 0x6a, 0x48, 0x5a, 0x27, 0x93, 0x26, 0x59,
        0xe7, 0x71, 0x9b, 0x37, 0xc3, 0xa7, 0x9f, 0x42, 0xf7, 0xee, 0xc2, 0xf8, 0xf1, 0xfe, 0x5f, 0x4f,
        0x63, 0x97, 0x57, 0x05, 0x12, 0x40, 0x64, 0x65, 0x09, 0xa9, 0xa9, 0x76, 0x7b, 0xf6, 0x6c, 0xe8,
        0xd6, 0xcd, 0xf3, 0xae, 0x1d, 0x1a, 0x6a, 0xc3, 0xda, 0x6e, 0x71, 0x9c, 0xfb, 0xce, 0xe3, 0x0d,
        0x4d, 0xeb, 0xe4, 0xda, 0x35, 0xb8, 0x72, 0xc5, 0xce, 0x0e, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0xb5, 0xdd, 0x9a, 0xab,
        0x57, 0xfd, 0xbf, 0xa6, 0xc6, 0x2e, 0xaf, 0x0a, 0x24, 0x40, 0xd8, 0xb1, 0x43, 0x58, 0xb3, 0xc6,
        0x0a, 0x22, 0x25, 0x05, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xbd, 0x77, 0x69, 0x7a, 0xf6, 0xb4, 0x61, 0x6d, 0xc7, 0x6c,
        0xce, 0xfd, 0xe8, 0x68, 0xff, 0xd2, 0xba, 0x9e, 0x4e, 0xc1, 0xd5, 0xab, 0x86, 0x09, 0x13, 0xec,
        0xd3, 0xa4, 0xd2, 0x52, 0xc3, 0xda, 0xb5, 0xfe, 0x5f, 0x57, 0x63, 0x97, 0x57, 0x05, 0x12, 0x00,
        0x6c, 0xd9, 0x22, 0x6c, 0xd8, 0x60, 0x00, 0x61, 0xc6, 0x0c, 0xeb, 0xd4, 0xc0, 0x17, 0x8f, 0x3e,
        0x6a, 0xc3, 0x8c, 0x0c, 0x28, 0x28, 0xb0, 0x9e, 0x40, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0xec, 0xe8, 0x33, 0xc0, 0xff,
        0xfe, 0xe7, 0x5f, 0x5a, 0x80, 0x3d, 0x7b, 0x84, 0xef, 0xbe, 0x33, 0x44, 0x46, 0x0a, 0x43, 0x87,
        0xda, 0x81, 0xa9, 0xb0, 0x30, 0x61, 0xff, 0x7e, 0xc3, 0xb7, 0xdf, 0xfa, 0x37, 0x06, 0xd1, 0x98,
        0xe5, 0x0d, 0x54, 0x74, 0x24, 0xbd, 0x16, 0x1b, 0x37, 0xba, 0x3b, 0xae, 0x5e, 0xba, 0x54, 0x38,
        0x70, 0xc0, 0x53, 0x44, 0xf1, 0xf1, 0xc2, 0x2b, 0xaf, 0xb8, 0xc7, 0xdf, 0x6a, 0xda, 0xcb, 0x97,
        0xad, 0x97, 0xc6, 0x3f, 0xff, 0x34, 0x2c, 0x5c, 0x28, 0x0c, 0x1a, 0x64, 0x6e, 0xda, 0x44, 0xa9,
        0xa9, 0x86, 0xb6, 0x6d, 0x85, 0xd5, 0xab, 0xb9, 0x59, 0x8e, 0xfa, 0xca, 0x5c, 0xf3, 0xbf, 0x6b,
        0x8c, 0xf2, 0x06, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x27, 0xfd, 0x16, 0x99, 0x3b, 0x17, 0x92, 0x92, 0x84, 0xf0, 0x70,
        0x21, 0x28, 0xc8, 0x86, 0x49, 0x49, 0xc2, 0x9c, 0x39, 0xfe, 0xa7, 0x7d, 0xff, 0x7d, 0x2b, 0x8e,
        0xfb, 0xee, 0x73, 0x89, 0xc3, 0x79, 0x57, 0x8f, 0x8e, 0x16, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x0d, 0xef, 0xbd, 0xd7,
        0x74, 0xca, 0xab, 0x2d, 0x08, 0x3a, 0x6b, 0x4d, 0x51, 0xb4, 0x05, 0x51, 0x14, 0x35, 0xd2, 0x15,
        0x45, 0x05, 0xa2, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x45, 0x51, 0x81, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x51, 0x54, 0x20,
        0x8a, 0xa2, 0x02, 0x51, 0x94, 0x40, 0x42, 0x5d, 0x8f, 0xfe, 0x4d, 0x6a, 0xbf, 0x06, 0xe2, 0x70,
        0x08, 0x51, 0x51, 0xf0, 0xd4, 0x53, 0xb8, 0x8d, 0x92, 0xd7, 0x4c, 0x3b, 0x7a, 0xb4, 0x30, 0x69,
        0x92, 0xf1, 0x99, 0x97, 0xb7, 0x41, 0xdb, 0xeb, 0xd7, 0x85, 0xec, 0x6c, 0xbb, 0x22, 0xed, 0xd9,
        0xb3, 0xf6, 0x4d, 0x60, 0x87, 0xc3, 0xae, 0xf1, 0xd1, 0xab, 0x97, 0x5d, 0xe3, 0x23, 0x26, 0x46,
        0x3d, 0x91, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x9a, 0x38, 0xe5, 0xe5, 0x86, 0xe3, 0xc7, 0xe1, 0xf8, 0x71, 0x58, 0xb0,
        0x40, 0x88, 0x8b, 0xf3, 0xac, 0xb4, 0x99, 0x99, 0xf0, 0xc4, 0x13, 0x42, 0x44, 0xc4, 0xad, 0x55,
        0xe8, 0xa2, 0x22, 0xe1, 0xf5, 0xd7, 0xed, 0x84, 0xaa, 0x9a, 0x94, 0x95, 0xc1, 0x99, 0x33, 0xf6,
        0xb3, 0x73, 0xa7, 0xbe, 0x0d, 0xa1, 0x02, 0x69, 0xc2, 0x38, 0x2b, 0xe7, 0xa5, 0x4b, 0xc2, 0xfa,
        0xf5, 0x90, 0x9b, 0x6b, 0x48, 0x4f, 0x77, 0x5f, 0x74, 0xd3, 0x49, 0x75, 0xb5, 0x61, 0xdd, 0x3a,
        0x61, 0xf1, 0xe2, 0xfa, 0xf3, 0xbd, 0x7e, 0xdd, 0x25, 0x8e, 0xce, 0x9d, 0x85, 0xa4, 0x24, 0x88,
        0x8d, 0xb5, 0x4b, 0x46, 0xdf, 0xb8, 0x61, 0x1d, 0x4d, 0x1c, 0x3b, 0xe6, 0x5c, 0x58, 0x54, 0x5b,
        0x10, 0x15, 0x48, 0x13, 0x27, 0x2c, 0xcc, 0x30, 0x6d, 0x9a, 0x90, 0x9b, 0x0b, 0xbf, 0xfc, 0xe2,
        0x3d, 0x4d, 0xff, 0xfe, 0x42, 0x41, 0x81, 0x21, 0x3f, 0x5f, 0x7c, 0xce, 0x45, 0x71, 0x92, 0x9d,
        0x6d, 0xc5, 0x11, 0x11, 0x61, 0x17, 0x14, 0xad, 0x39, 0x57, 0xbd, 0x45, 0x0b, 0xe8, 0xda, 0xd5,
        0x7e, 0x9c, 0x8b, 0x75, 0x2a, 0x6a, 0xa4, 0xff, 0xe7, 0x79, 0xee, 0x39, 0x08, 0x0a, 0xb2, 0x2d,
        0x4d, 0x79, 0x79, 0xdd, 0x73, 0x3f, 0x72, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x38, 0x6e, 0x9c, 0x7f, 0x8e, 0x1c, 0x14,
        0x6d, 0x41, 0x9a, 0x14, 0x25, 0x25, 0xc2, 0x86, 0x0d, 0x76, 0xbb, 0x5b, 0x37, 0xef, 0x69, 0xba,
        0x74, 0x31, 0x8c, 0x1a, 0x25, 0x7c, 0xf1, 0x85, 0x61, 0xfb, 0x76, 0x61, 0xec, 0x58, 0xdf, 0xf9,
        0x9d, 0x3b, 0x67, 0xc3, 0xd8, 0xd8, 0xba, 0x1f, 0x0e, 0xf8, 0x32, 0xee, 0x15, 0x15, 0x48, 0x93,
        0xc0, 0x55, 0x61, 0x5d, 0x77, 0xf9, 0x31, 0x63, 0x7c, 0xa7, 0x1f, 0x37, 0xce, 0x4e, 0x90, 0xca,
        0xc8, 0x80, 0x61, 0xc3, 0x84, 0x0e, 0x1d, 0xbc, 0xb7, 0x0e, 0xd7, 0xae, 0xd9, 0xf0, 0xf6, 0xdb,
        0xf5, 0x37, 0xd6, 0x2e, 0x56, 0x33, 0xc0, 0xe1, 0x10, 0x7a, 0xf5, 0x12, 0x16, 0x2e, 0xac, 0xdb,
        0xbe, 0xb8, 0xe3, 0x0e, 0x43, 0x72, 0x32, 0x54, 0x54, 0x18, 0x3e, 0xfc, 0xd0, 0x77, 0x7e, 0x21,
        0x21, 0x36, 0xac, 0xed, 0xcc, 0x21, 0x33, 0xd3, 0xf5, 0x51, 0xb4, 0x05, 0x69, 0xf2, 0xb8, 0x2a,
        0xea, 0xad, 0xdb, 0x09, 0x23, 0x46, 0xc0, 0x57, 0x5f, 0x09, 0xb9, 0xb9, 0x86, 0x23, 0x47, 0xc4,
        0xeb, 0xb9, 0x5d, 0xba, 0xd8, 0xb5, 0xcd, 0x4f, 0x9e, 0xf4, 0xfe, 0x44, 0x4c, 0xd1, 0x16, 0xa4,
        0xd9, 0x12, 0x1c, 0x6c, 0x98, 0x3c, 0xd9, 0x6e, 0xfb, 0xf2, 0x66, 0x12, 0x1f, 0x6f, 0xc3, 0xf4,
        0x74, 0xa8, 0xac, 0x54, 0x87, 0xd2, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x00, 0xa3, 0x5f, 0x3f, 0xc3, 0xa0, 0x41, 0xc2,
        0x85, 0x0b, 0xc6, 0x67, 0x2b, 0x13, 0x1e, 0x2e, 0x14, 0x16, 0x1a, 0xe6, 0xcf, 0xb7, 0x5e, 0xd9,
        0xaf, 0x5c, 0x11, 0x6e, 0xdc, 0x10, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x85, 0xcc, 0x4c, 0x15, 0x8d, 0x76, 0xb1, 0x9a,
        0x39, 0x93, 0x26, 0xd9, 0x8a, 0x5f, 0x55, 0xe5, 0x29, 0x92, 0xd6, 0xad, 0x0d, 0xaf, 0xbe, 0x2a,
        0x2c, 0x5e, 0x2c, 0x9c, 0x3a, 0x65, 0xbc, 0x0e, 0x2e, 0x06, 0x05, 0x09, 0x53, 0xa7, 0x36, 0xac,
        0x7b, 0xa7, 0x68, 0x0b, 0xf2, 0x9f, 0xa1, 0x73, 0x67, 0x53, 0xa7, 0x6b, 0x9f, 0x6e, 0xdd, 0x0c,
        0xef, 0xbe, 0x0b, 0xc9, 0xc9, 0x42, 0x54, 0x94, 0x5d, 0xc3, 0x23, 0x38, 0x58, 0xe8, 0xd0, 0x41,
        0x18, 0x3e, 0xdc, 0xba, 0x08, 0x1a, 0x35, 0x4a, 0xc5, 0xd1, 0x18, 0xa8, 0x57, 0x13, 0x45, 0xf1,
        0x82, 0x7a, 0x35, 0x51, 0x14, 0xed, 0x62, 0x29, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x51, 0x54, 0x20, 0x8a, 0xa2,
        0x02, 0x51, 0x14, 0x15, 0x88, 0xa2, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x14, 0x45, 0x05, 0xa2, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x45,
        0x51, 0x81, 0x28, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0x02, 0x51, 0x14, 0x15, 0x88, 0xa2, 0xa8, 0x40, 0x14, 0x45, 0x05,
        0xa2, 0x28, 0x2a, 0x10, 0x45, 0x51, 0x81, 0x28, 0x8a, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x51, 0x9a, 0x1d, 0x37, 0x67,
        0x14, 0x2a, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0x2d, 0x88, 0xa2, 0x34, 0x88, 0xff, 0x03, 0x50, 0x16, 0x99, 0xc7, 0xb6,
        0xbc, 0x82, 0xa6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x49, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0xae, 0x42, 0x60, 0x82
    ).buffer], { type: "image/png" });
}
```

### `Worker`

To create a URL for JavaScript code to use in a `Worker`, it's the same sort of thing as above, use a `Blob` and `createObjectURL`:

```js
// Create a blob containing the worker code
const blob = new Blob([
    `postMessage("Hi from the worker!");`
], { type: "text/javascript" })

// Create a URL to give to the Worker constructor
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Create the worker
const worker = new Worker(url);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

To avoid worrying about delimiters (the above would be awkward if you wanted to use a template literal in your code), you can put the text in its own `script` tag using a non-JavaScript `type`:

```js
// Create a blob containing the worker code
const blob = new Blob([
    document.getElementById("worker").textContent
], { type: "text/javascript" })

// Create a URL for the Worker constructor
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

// Create the worker
const worker = new Worker(url);
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

```html
<!-- Here's the web worker code. Since the type is javascript/worker, it won't be run by the browser -->
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
postMessage("Hi from the worker!");
</script>
```

Comment: This only works with UTF-8 texts, which is a very minor case of FileReader uses in StackOverflow. You can very well `fetch` as blob a binary data from a known reliable source if the exact file is not important (e.g for images, or videos, `https://upload.wikimedia` is great), if you need to embed some small non UTF-8 text resource, you can also very well paste a base64 representation of that data. Using an <input type="file"> is not uncommon at all too. Finally, with template literals, you can include small Workers script in a less convoluted way directly in the js part of the snippet.

Comment: @Kaiido - No, it's not limited to UTF-8 text, you can create a `Blob` with any content you need. Good point about using a file input when the actual content doesn't matter. Would you post an answer demonstrating what you're saying about using template literals to create a worker inline? I haven't seen that (and can't see how template literals have anything to do with it, unless you just mean as a convenience to avoid issues with quotes).

Comment: I am talking about using <script> as the holder for your data. Here you can only hold UTF-8 text data, there is no way to demonstrate how reading a Shift-JIS text for instance behaves. And for the template literals, it's also about the use of the <script> + DOM reading. `const worker_script = \`onmessage=e=>console.log('hello');\`const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([worker_script]), { type:'text/javascript'});` is IMM clearer with small worker scripts. And unfortunately I don't really have the time to write a tutorial like answer myself, hence my poor comments... sorry.

Comment: @Kaiido - Ah, okay. I thought you meant there was a way avoiding the `Blob`. Yeah, you can do it that way too -- provided the code doesn't have any template literals in it. That's why I use a `script` tag, no worries about delimiters (well, other than `</script>`). :-) I've added a direct example, though, no reason not to.